# Printing out zeros after decimals into excel

Tags: c#, excel, console.writeline

I am trying to print out a `double` to excel.  In my GUI the number prints out correctly.

But when I write the number to an excel file the number comes out with out the zeros after the decimal place.  For examples the number `1.10` prints out correctly in my GUI, but in excel in prints out `1.1`.

```
double foo = 1.10;
writeline(foo.ToString("F2"));
```

I have tried `String.Format("{0:0.00}", foo.ToString("F2"));` without resolving this issue.  I am pretty sure the problem is when the number gets into excel, excel truncates all zeros after the decimal place.  Is there a way to send excel a message to print out two places after the decimal?

I am working on someone elses code that opens and closes the excel file.   They are using `File.Create` and `StreamWriter` to create and open the excel file

Comment: How do you "send to excel"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", foo.ToString("F2"));
```

won't work, because you're trying to format something, that is converted to string already.
Use a direct variable - your foo should return a numeric value and then you'd be able to use it like this (example):

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", foo.GetDouble("F2"));
```

In other words:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", "1.10");    //wrong
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 1.10d);     //correct
```

Comment: It still prints out 1.1 instead of 1.10 in excel

Comment: The it's not a c# related problem. Columns in excel file are filtered to round needless zeroes. You're sending right values, but you're not setting correct column properties.

Comment: I figured that, is there a way to send the message into excel to print out .00?

Comment: There's no such thing as "sending a message into excel". You're using some kind of enigmous access method you have not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen too many complex answers for a simple problem, I had the same problem too that's why I came here but I didn't get any reasonable answers. I figured it out though, just highlight the column, right click on it ---- format cells-----a dialogue box will come up, go under category---Number, then add as many decimal places as you want.